# Python not working in CMD, but no error thrown

Tags: python, windows

I have a really strange Problem with Python when used from the command prompt under Windows 10.
When I put "python --version" in the command prompt, nothing happens, this also means no error is thrown.
I cannot run any python script from the console, altough the path variables are set properly and I re-installed python 3.6 several times. It seems also to cause this error when no Python is installed on the system at all. Anyone an idea, what could cause such a strange behaviour?

[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxen1.png)

Edit: I tried now "where python", which gives me two path:

```
C:\Users\set>where python
C:\Users\set\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Python36\python.exe
```

I removed the first path, which caused the error. It pointed somehow to an empty .exe

Comment: Can you please try python3 --version?

Comment: Sounds like the `python` command is something that does nothing. What's the output of `where python`?

Comment: "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" is an app-execution alias for the store app. If it's not installed, it's supposed to open the Microsoft Store to let you install it. But you already have a full installation of 3.6 and probably don't want the store app. So go into your app settings and disable the app-execution aliases for the "python", "python3", and "python3.x" commands, plus any for IDLE and pip that are set.

Comment: The standard installation does not include "python3" and "python3.x" commands, in contrast to the store app. For any instructions coming from Unix users that tell you to use "python3", in Windows just use "python" -- or, if you installed the launcher, use "py -X[.Y][-32|-64]" to run a particular installed version.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try `python3 --version`

Comment: I tried and it resulted in the same --> No error thrown. When I use python4 --version, the CMD throws an error (just to verify if a wrongly input is handled correctly)